# Merging a Keras layer

Tags: keras, keras-layer

How can one merge two inputs in one layer where each element of `input1` is multiplied each element of `input2`?

Say, I have two inputs, Dense(3) with `x1, x2, x3,` and Dense(4) with `y1, y2, y3` and `y4`. How can one merge the two inputs into one layer where `z1=x1*y1, z2=x1*y2, z3=x1*y3, z4=x1*y4, z5=x2*y1`...?

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the shape, transpose if you need it, and then use the dot function.

https://keras.io/layers/merge/#dot

Answer (score 0):

```
merge = keras.layers.Dot(axes=(1,2), normalize=False)
```